# TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
constructor() {
  super()
  this.state = {
    privilegesOption: privilegesOption: [{
      key: 1,
      text: "Admin",
      value: 1
    }, {
      key: 2,
      text: "Cashier",
      value: 2
    }]
  }
  this.foo = this.foo.bind(this)
}

foo() {
  let privilegesOut = this.state.privilegesOption.find(e => e.value === 1);
  console.log(privilegesOut.text)
}
```

Why i keep get this error if i call object property after using .find ? 
if i use this.state.privilegesOption[0].text, its worked

Comment: Your `privilegesOption` object does not contain a key `value` so your `find` is not returning anything. Even if it did, none of your objects have a `text` property

Comment: `privilegesOption` isn't an array, so I'm surprised you're not getting an error when trying to use `.find()`

Comment: @NickParsons it's invalid syntax, he will get an error much earlier.

Comment: Sorry, i copy wrong object and edit it already

Comment: @ASDFGerte oh yes, you're right, missed the additional object that was there

Answer (score 0):

A few erros with this which is best answered with some space, I think what you were trying to do was this, I have turned `privilegesOption` into an array `[]` containing objects `{}` where the object key:value pairs are seperated by a comma `,`

```
this.state = {
    privilegesOption: [
        {
            key: 1,
            text: "Admin",
            value: 1
        },
        {
            key: 2,
            text: "Cashier",
            value: 2
        }
    ]
}
```

And to `find` the object where value is 1 you were completely right

```
let privilagesOut = this.state.privilegesOption.find(x => x.value == 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your posted code snippet has a syntax error (press "Run code snippet" to see it).
Here is a complete code snippet with fixed syntax errors:

```js
class Y {}
class X extends Y {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      privilegesOption: [
        {
          key: 1,
          text: "Admin",
          value: 1
        },
        {
          key: 2,
          text: "Cashier",
          value: 2
        }
      ]
    };

    let privilegesOut = this.state.privilegesOption.find(e => e.value === 1);
    console.log(privilegesOut.text);
  }
}
new X();
```

It successfully outputs "Admin" on the console.